# Update several mysql entries at once from PHP table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table with some data from a mysql database. I need to update that information from within the table itself so when I press the button submit (table is inside a form) I need that all that data gets updated on the database. I can get the information from the database with no problem but I'm unable to update it! Here is the code:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 width=960px style='font-size:10px'> 
<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='itself.php'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan=3> People on the list </th>
<th><input type='submit' name='filtrar' id='filtrar' value='Filtrar'/></th>
<th><input type='submit' name='modificar' id='modificar' value='Modificar'/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><label for='id'>ID</label></th>
<th><label for='id'>Friends</label></th>
<th><label for='id'>On the list?</label></th>
</tr>


<?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_listas, MYSQLI_BOTH))
$id= $row['id'];
{
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo "$row[id]" ?>
</td>
<td><select name='friends[<? echo "$id" ?>]' size='1' id='friends[<? echo "$id" ?>]'>
<option selected='selected'><? echo "$row[friends]" ?></option>
<option>less than 10</option>
<option>more than 10</option>   
</select>
</td>
<td><select name='onlist[<? echo "$id" ?>]' size='1' id='onlist[<? echo "$id" ?>]'>
<option selected='selected'><? echo "$row[onlist]" ?></option>
<option>SI</option>
<option>NO</option> 
</select>
</td>

<? 
$ssql_min="select min(id) as id from listas_old";
$result_min=  mysqli_query($link, $ssql_min);
$resultado_min = mysqli_fetch_array($result_min, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$ssql_max="select max(id) as id from listas_old";
$result_max=  mysqli_query($link, $ssql_max);
$resultado_max = mysqli_fetch_array($result_max, MYSQLI_BOTH);      

if(isset($_POST[modificar]))

{
for($i=$resultado_min['id']; $i<$resultado_max['id']; $i++)
            {
$sql1="UPDATE listas_old SET friends='$friends[$i]', onlist='$onlist[$i]' WHERE id='$i'";
$result1=mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [OP wrote in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat):

> Got the solution for myself! This is what I did...
>
> Change the `for` sentence like this:
>
> ```
> for($i=$resultado_min['id'];
>     $i<=$resultado_max['id'];
>     $i++) {
>     $friendsfor= $_POST['friends('.$i.')'];
>     $onlistfor= $_POST['onlist('.$i.')'];
>     $sql1="UPDATE listas_old SET friends='$friendsfor', anotado= '$onlistfor' WHERE id='$i'";
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have your quotes all wrong in the update. You are trying to concatenate a string (your update sql) with php variables. But you need to make sure that php recognizes them as a variable instead of just as a string.

Should be like this

```
$sql1= "UPDATE listas_old SET friends='" . $friends[$i] . "', onlist='" . $onlist[$i] . "' WHERE id='" . $i . "'";
```

You only need to add in the single quotes if you are adding a varchar or date or something. If it is an int, you don't need the single quotes. Also I'm not sure what onlist would do, or if that is valid.

Comment: i've tried that and is not working. Besides i use the same syntax for the sql query to show the data on the table and its working. :(

Comment: well in your queries you aren't adding in php variables, so the quoting thing doesn't matter. You should try and take the update query and just run it in mysql itself. See if that works. If it does then make sure that your variables have the right values in them by echoing them out before you do the actual update

Comment: Got the solution for myself guys!. This is what i did...change the for sentence like this:


    for($i=$resultado_min['id']; $i<=$resultado_max['id']; $i++)
    {
    $friendsfor= $_POST['friends('.$i.')'];
    $onlistfor= $_POST['onlist('.$i.')'];
    $sql1="UPDATE listas_old SET friends='$friendsfor', anotado= '$onlistfor' WHERE id='$i'";
    }